# Delphi XE6 TForm.AutoSize

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe6

I've code in Delphi XE2 who work perfectly. But in Delphi XE6 it doesn't work.
I create a Tform with the property AutoSize to true. I use a TPanel align alTop with a button for create some another panels.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   t :TPanel;
begin
   t := TPanel.Create(self);
   t.Parent := self;
   t.Align := alTop;
end;
```

The form doesn't auto size. If I want to see all my panels I have to move the form (or try to resize, ....).

Have you any idea's ?

Comment: Seems to work ok in XE5. Installing XE6 om my laptop, may take a while ...

Comment: AutoSize -> Adjust form size automatically. alTop -> Adjust panel size automatically. No good using both, one of them should have precedence, which would purely depend on implementation detail.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm not so sure – `alTop` does more than adjust size, it positions controls too.

Comment: @David - What it does more does not change the fact that it is resized automatically to fit in its parent.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It seems to me that `AutoSize` and `Align` are expected to work together. When you put aligned controls in an auto-sized container, the controls are no longer resized. The controls are positioned, and the container is resized to match the size of the controls. Not that I can find any documentation to that effect.

Comment: @David - Incomplete documentation wouldn't surprise me. However it's not straightforward to implement.. Consider an alTop and an alBottom panel with different widths... The outcome would still depend on implementation detail.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes it would.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a change in behaviour. I can reproduce what you report. Namely that your code results in the form size changing in XE2, but not in XE6.

To work around this you can manually call `AdjustSize`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Panel: TPanel;
begin
  Panel := TPanel.Create(self);
  Panel.Parent := Self;
  Panel.Top := ClientHeight;
  Panel.Align := alTop;
  AdjustSize;
end;
```

Comment: `Panel.Parent := Self;` triggers `OnFormResize` event in XE5, but not in XE6. I'm puzzled why this change in behaviour was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Not align, use anchors:

```
t.Anchors:=[TAnchorKind.akTop];
```

This is from my XE5 (have no XE6)

Comment: Make sure to position and size the Panel where you want it before you then Anchor it.